# Why I'm getting Type Mismatch error in a create request with a lookup field?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am having an error of type when I am going to create an entity in the crm by web api, part of the message in the error is:

> Type Mismatch: Type of Attribute: new_rga.stageid is: System.Guid. However, Type of passed-in value is: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference

My entity is called "*new_rga*" and there's a field of type "*processstage*" which your logical name is "*processstage_new_rga*".

My code:

```
Guid stageID = new Guid("27kj9503-5967-42cf-a4c9-1d20f0e09921");
item["processstage_new_rga@odata.bind"] = "/processstages("+stageID.ToString()+")";
```

In the metada:

```
<NavigationProperty Name="processstage_new_rga" Type="mscrm.processstage" Nullable="false" Partner="processstage_new_rga">
       <ReferentialConstraint Property="_stageid_value" ReferencedProperty="processstageid"/>
</NavigationProperty>
```

I am not understanding why this error, since visually it seems to be right.

Comment: are you sure to be using the correct field ? somehow i dont understand how do you have stageid field on your custom entity. BPF stages are handelt in separate entity.

there might be stageid and processid directly on the entity but those are deprecated.

Comment: @minohimself exactly. I think that’s the confusion, try string assignment instead

Comment: The pure value (string or Guid) did not work. Unfortunately i don't know much about the BPF stages, it is a legacy system that is being passed from the old service to web api.